# django how to delete query object from template

Tags: django, templates, view, sql-delete

how can I perform an object delete from queryset when I click some button in template for django view

here is my code ...

**HTML**
[image]

**views.py**

```
def CamerasList(request):
model = Cameras
# This function can hadle both the retrieval of the view, as well as the submission of the form on the view.
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CamerasForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.delete_cam_id = request.POST.get('delete_cam_id')
        deletelement = Cameras.objects.get(pk=form.delete_cam_id)
        deletelement.delete()

var = {}
var = user_group_validation(request)
theuser = request.user
theuserid = Users.objects.get(user_id=theuser.id).pk
theorgid = Users.objects.get(pk=theuserid).organization_id.pk

if var['grupo'] == 'superuser':
    object_list = Cameras.objects.all()
    organization = Organizations.objects.all()
    url = request.session['url']
if var['grupo'] == 'admin' or var['grupo'] == 'user':
    object_list = Cameras.objects.filter(organization_id=request.session['userInc'])
    organization = Organizations.objects.filter(id=request.session['userInc'])
    url = request.session['url']

template = get_template(app+u'/cameras_list.html')
return HttpResponse(template.render(locals()))
```

Comment: Hi there!  So, you want to delete and render the page again, or just delete the entry?

Comment: hello ! thanks for replying.. actually, delete and render the page again is ok.

Comment: So...  general ideia is ok. But i dont understand why you use forms to do this. I mean, after the `if POST` you can access the hidden input from the html with  request.POST['action'] (the name of the input turns into a dictionary key). Anyway, what happens when you run your code? do you have any error message from django? Which part exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: the thing is I am not getting any error from django at all, the only thing is that the object is not deleted from the database, maybe if I try the request post calling at the main level of the function ?

Comment: No error and not deleting is weird. First check if the you are receiving the correct pk from the html form and using the correct key.  Rewrite your `if POST` block with the line: `print([(x,y) for x,y in request.POST.items()])`. request.POST is just a dictionary object. Check if `delete_cam_id` is the correct key for the pk you want, which I don't think it is. This is the name of the span tag. Pretty sure request.POST receives the name of the input tag, which is `action` in your case.

Comment: Yes it was weird, indeed ! That is exactly why I opened this issue in here, but let me tell you that I got the solution already. What I did is to put the reques POST call in the main level of the view function, that gave me the variables that I needed, and I checked them as you told in this comment. All working perfect, now I delete objects from my app and from the database... thanks again for your help

Comment: Cool! glad to help!